# What process do you use to convert from a string to an encryption password for XOR encryption?

Tags: encryption, xor

I am attempting Project Euler task 59, where you need to decrypt a string of numbers encrypted with XOR encryption. I understand the process of applying XOR to 2 binary numbers, but I don't understand how to convert a 3 letter password to binary. I first thought that you would convert each letter into ascii, then convert each of those numbers individually into binary, and then by concatenating them yielding a final key. But I then thought that you could also convert each character into ascii, *then* concatenate the denary numbers to give a single base 10 number, then convert that into binary. Is one of these methods correct or is it something else?

I am attempting this in Python 3.

Comment: It could be any scheme you could imagine. Without a specification, we can only speculate as to what the right answer is.

Comment: If it could be any scheme I can imagine, how can I hope to decrypt it?

Comment: The instructions are very clear. Convert each character to its ASCII value, which is an integer, then XOR. You don't have to "convert" the integer to binary unless your programming language doesn't have an XOR operator.